AG-Grid React: How to suppress the internal logic of the Home/End keys?
I've tried but can't figure out how to suppress the internal logic of the Home/End keys?
The internal Home/End key logic fires BEFORE any ag-grid events, so I can't suppress it... or I don't know how...
I tried using internal suppression logic, adding event listeners, testing "onCellKeyDown" prop, etc.

Take a look at the folowing example on how to suppress certain keys:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#example-suppress-keyboard-navigation
You can suppress keys per column by setting the suppressKeyboardEvent in a a column definition:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-columns-suppressKeyboardEvent

I tried it.
This does not work.
All of this functionality is called AFTER the internal logic (for example - rows are moved) of the End key has already been executed.
